# ANRLR4 lexer semantic predicate issue

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to use a semantic predicate in the lexer to look ahead one token but somehow I can't get it right. Here's what I have:

**lexer grammar**

```
lexer grammar TLLexer;

DirStart
    : { getCharPositionInLine() == 0 }? '#dir'
    ;

DirEnd
    : { getCharPositionInLine() == 0 }? '#end'
    ;

Cont
    : 'contents' [ \t]* -> mode(CNT)
    ;

WS
    : [ \t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

NL
    : '\r'? '\n'
    ;

mode CNT;

CNT_DirEnd
    : '#end' [ \t]* '\n'?
      { System.out.println("--matched end--"); }
    ;

CNT_LastLine
    : ~ '\n'* '\n'
      { _input.LA(1) == CNT_DirEnd }? -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE)
    ;

CNT_Line
    : ~ '\n'* '\n'
    ;
```

**parser grammar**

```
parser grammar TLParser;

options { tokenVocab = TLLexer; }

dirs
    : ( dir
      | NL
      )*
    ;

dir
    : DirStart Cont 
      contents
      DirEnd
    ;

contents
    : CNT_Line* CNT_LastLine
    ;
```

Essentially each line in the stuff in the CNT mode is free-form, but it never begins with #end followed by optional whitespace. Basically I want to keep matching the **#end** tag in the default lexer mode.

My test input is as follows:

```
#dir contents
 ..line..
#end
```

If I run this in grun I get the following

```
$ grun TL dirs test.txt 
--matched end--
line 3:0 extraneous input '#end\n' expecting {CNT_LastLine, CNT_Line}
```

So clearly CNT_DirEnd gets matched, but somehow the predicate doesn't detect it.

I know that this this particular task doesn't require a semantic predicate, but that's just the part that doesn't work. The actual parser, while it may be written without the predicate, will be a lot less clean if I simply move the matching of the the **#end** tag into the mode CNT.

Thanks,
Kesha.

Comment: It seems CNT_Line as defined is not matching '..line..'

Comment: @ThomasG It does match it, which you can see it with the -gui option, or if you add print actions to CNT_Line (then grun prints it 3 times, because it can never escape the CNT mode) and CNT_LastLine (never prints it).

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. The member **_input** represents the characters of the original input, thus **_input.LA** returns characters, not lexer token IDs (is that the correct term?). Either way, the numbers returned by the lexer to the parser have nothing to do with the values returned by _input.LA, hence the predicate fails unless by some weird luck the character value returned by **_input.LA(1)** is equal to the lexer ID of *CNT_DirEnd*.

I modified the lexer as shown below and now it works, even though it is not as elegant as I hoped it would be (maybe someone knows a better way?)

```
lexer grammar TLLexer;

@lexer::members {
    private static final String END_DIR = "#end";

    private boolean isAtEndDir() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int n = 1;
        int ic;

        // read characters until EOF
        while ((ic = _input.LA(n++)) != -1) {
            char c = (char) ic;
            // we're interested in the next line only
            if (c == '\n') break;
            if (c == '\r') continue;
            sb.append(c);
        }

        // Does the line begin with #end ?
        if (sb.indexOf(END_DIR) != 0) return false;
        // Is the #end followed by whitespace only?
        for (int i = END_DIR.length(); i < sb.length(); i++) {
            switch (sb.charAt(i)) {
            case ' ':
            case '\t':
                continue;
            default: return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

[skipped .. nothing changed in the default mode]

mode CNT;

/* removed CNT_DirEnd */

CNT_LastLine
    : ~ '\n'* '\n'
      { isAtEndDir() }? -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE)
    ;

CNT_Line
    : ~ '\n'* '\n'
    ;
```